# SQL Server 2005/2008 Licensing Decision

Tags: sql-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hello,

I have purchased a dedicated server from a reputable Hosting company. They only have Windows Server 2008 OS installed on it and NO Sql server. Server Configuration is Intel Dual core Processor with 2GB of RAM and 100GB HDD.

I wanted to host my web services on that server which will be using the MS SQL Server 2005 at the backend.There are multiple web services and each using a different Database.

Microsoft has CAL basis Licensing , Which I understand is based on number of users accessing the database directly ( I may be wrong ) . But my users will be accessing the webservice and no direct connection to the database as such. Yes but the number of users accessing the web server cannot be known and is not under my control.

Which Licensing is best suited for this kind of setup ? I don't need analysing and BI services right now ,but i may want to upgrade that in future may be.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my users will be accessing the
>   webservice and no direct connection to
>   the database as such.

No, reality does not work like that. A user is a use (end user) whether you aggregate them or not.

In your case, SPLA processor licensing applies. SQL Server Web edition. Which is about 20 USD or so per month.

Go on the MS SPLA Website (http://www.microsoft.com/spla), sign a SPLA contract.

Facturally it is the ONLY legal licensing you have - anything else is illegal in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks I went through the content , am in process of talking to a SPLA reseller in my country. One thing is clear , Microsoft's licensing is not so easy.

Comment: Actually it is quite easy. Try oracle for a change ;) YOu need an oracle to go through that. SPLA is quite easy, quite nice for providers (pay monthly etc.).

Comment: :) yes may be you are right. SPLA is much simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great explanation of the options.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365262/microsoft-sql-server-licensing

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx